# Given $m$ objects of type A and $n$ objects of type B, arrange them such that there are not more than two consecutive objects of type B.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, combinatorics-on-words

I came across this question on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Being-given-a-number-m-of-objects-of-type-A-and-a-number-n-of-objects-of-type-B-in-how-many-ways-can-we-create-a-bigger-object-of-length-m-n-combining-them-such-that-in-the-final-object-there-are-not-more-than-2) and got interested in solving it.

> Being given a number $m$ of objects of type A and a number $n$ of objects of type B, in how many ways can we create a bigger object of length $m+n$ combining them, such that in the final object there are not more than $2$ consecutive objects of type B?

[My attempt](https://www.quora.com/Being-given-a-number-m-of-objects-of-type-A-and-a-number-n-of-objects-of-type-B-in-how-many-ways-can-we-create-a-bigger-object-of-length-m-n-combining-them-such-that-in-the-final-object-there-are-not-more-than-2/answer/Sagnik-Saha-82):

> Take away $2x$ number of objects of type B and create a new type called C such that— **each object of type C is made up of two objects of type B**.
>
> Now we have:
> $\displaystyle \begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline \text{Type} & \text{No. of objects}\\ \hline A & m\\ \hline B & n-2x\\ \hline C & x\\ \hline \end{array} \tag*{}$
> Let’s represent objects of type B by | (lone pipe) and type C by || (double pipe).
> We need to arrange the objects of type A (represented by period .) in between the arrangements of objects of types B and C.
> $\underbrace{…}_{a_0}|\underbrace{…}_{a_1}||\underbrace{…}_{a_2}||\cdots\cdots|\underbrace{…}_{a_{n-x}}\tag*{}$
> Lone pipes and double pipes can permutate in $\displaystyle \frac{(n-2x+x)!}{(n-2x)!\cdot x!}=\binom{n-x}{x}\tag*{}$ ways. The figure is only representational, we are not sure about the order.
>
> Number of ways to arrange $m$ periods in between those lone and double pipes can be given by the number of *non-negative integer* solution sets of the following equation:
> $m=a_0+(1+a_1)+(1+a_2)+\ldots+(1+a_{n-x-1})+a_{n-x}\\ \displaystyle \implies m -(n-x-1) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-x}a_i\tag*{}$
> This equation has $\displaystyle \binom{m-(n-x-1)+n-x}{n-x}=\binom{m+1}{n-x}\tag*{}$ non-negative integer solution sets. ([Why?](https://themathhub.quora.com/How-many-non-negative-integer-solutions-does-the-equation-math-sum-limits_-i-0-m-x_i-n-math-have-for-a-given-mat)).
>
> Hence, we have $\displaystyle \binom{n-x}{x}\cdot \binom{m+1}{n-x}\tag*{}$ ways of arranging the double pipes, lone pipes and periods.
>
> Now the number of double pipes can be varied from $0$ to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ which gives us: $\displaystyle \color{red}{\boxed{\sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-x}{x}\cdot \binom{m+1}{n-x}}}\tag*{}$

I am not sure if this has a closed form or there is any mistake in my assesment. Any help or alternate solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Your formula is correct. Using the methods of the book [A = B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html), I found that there was no summation-free closed form for this summation.

Comment: @MikeEarnest with some added details that should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution that confirms OPs result. We consider a binary alphabet built from letters $A,B$. Words which do not have *any* consecutive equal letters are called *Smirnov words*. A generating function for Smirnov words is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{Az}{1+Az}-\frac{Bz}{1+Bz}\right)^{-1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The coefficient $[z^n]$ of $z^n$ in the series (1) gives the number of binary words of length $n$ which do not have any consecutive letters.

> In the current example we are looking for words which do not have any restriction on letters $A$. The letters $B$ may occur in runs of length one or two. We encode this situation as
> \begin{align*}
> Az\quad&\to\quad Az+\left(Az\right)^2+\left(Az\right)^3+\cdots=\frac{Az}{1+Az}\\
> Bz\quad&\to\quad Bz+\left(Bz\right)^2\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}

Putting (2) into (1) we derive the generating function
\begin{align*}
&\left(1-\frac{\frac{Az}{1-Az}}{1+\frac{Az}{1-Az}}-\frac{Bz+B^2z^2}{1+Bz+B^2z^2}\right)^{-1}\\
&\qquad=\left(1-Az-\frac{Bz+B^2z^2}{1+Bz+B^2z^2}\right)^{-1}\\
&\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1+Bz+B^2z^2}{1-Az\left(1+Bz+B^2z^2\right)}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> The wanted number of arrangements is the coefficient of $A^mB^nz^{m+n}$ of the generating function in (3). We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{[A^mB^nz^{m+n}]\frac{1+Bz+B^2z^2}{1-Az\left(1+Bz+B^2z^2\right)}}\\
> &\qquad=[A^mB^nz^{m+n}]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(Az)^k\left(1+Bz+B^2z^2\right)^{k+1}\tag{3.1}\\
> &\qquad=[B^nz^n]\left(1+Bz+B^2z^2\right)^{m+1}\tag{3.2}\\
> &\qquad=[B^nz^n]\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{k}(Bz)^k(1+Bz)^k\\
> &\qquad=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{k}[B^{n-k}z^{n-k}](1+Bz)^{k}\tag{3.3}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}}\tag{3.4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3.1) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)*.
- In (3.2) we select the coefficient of $A^mz^m$.
- In (3.3) we apply the rule $[z^p]z^qA(z)=[z^{p-q}]A(z)$.
- In (3.4) we select the coefficient of $B^{n-k}z^{n-k}$.

> Recalling that a binomial coefficient $\binom{p}{q}=0$ if $p,q$ are non-negative integer with $p<q$. We can transform the binomial sum (3.4) as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m+1}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m+1}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{k}\tag{$k\to n-k$}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}\binom{m+1}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{k}}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with OPs result.

**Note:** Smirnov words can be found for instance in example III.24 in  *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.

Comment: It's a huge book. For those unable to find it, the example $\textrm{III.24}$, Smirnov words is on page $221-222$ of the pdf (which is marked $204-205$ on the book)